# Problems with Macbook Pro '13 Retina screen

Tags: mac, graphics-card, intel-graphics, macbook-pro-retina

I have a weird issue in my retina screen: Apple Applications have clear graphics, but when it comes to open other applications (eg: Microsoft Office, Adobe Photoshop), all of the graphics stay blurred or pixelated, even the window's close button:

[image]

Is this normal for Retina screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Microsoft Office : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114778/microsoft-office-2011-interface-blurred-on-retina-display

Also make sure your Photoshop is updated.

Comment: I wonder if this was a update issue, but this happens in Maya, Photoshop, Microsoft,... happens in 80% of my installed applications

Comment: Make sure the applications support retina display.

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Some apps have not been developed to incorporate retina displays! Photoshop CS6 displays a high resolution interface as of 13.0.4 I think. The Microsoft Word 2016 Preview looks great on my rMBP. You can download the [Microsoft Office 2016 Preview for Mac](https://products.office.com/en-us/mac/mac-preview) and enjoy the retina resolution interface

This is not a problem with your Macbook screen or your graphics card!